# GCP Cloud code plugin in intellij "Failed to enable GCP auth addon"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-code

While trying to locally run the "java cloud run hello word sample" Cloud Run: Run Locally

I keep getting

> Enabling GCP auth addon...
>
> Failed to enable GCP auth addon. Deployment will continue but GCP
> credentials will not be added to minikube. Please ensure you have up
> to date application default credentials (ADC) by running `gcloud auth login --update-adc`

Things that I have tried and didn't solve the problem

- run `gcloud auth login --update-adc`
- use a different service account
- not provide a service account
- provide the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

[Current configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKbaP.png)

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Max, can you please open an issue at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues and include your IDE version, Cloud Code version, and OS? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, Matthew, for your suggestion https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues/2949

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be a bug with `minikube`

**The workaround:**

1. Install `minikube` https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/
2. In your terminal, run `minikube delete --all`
3. Delete the existing minikube images from Docker

The original workaround and issue details can be found below:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues/2949#issuecomment-870120602

Comment: Please could you add to the post the workaround, I guess it will add value to your answer: 1.     minikube delete --all
2. Delete the existing minikube images from docker